# How to apply migrations from code (EF Core)

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, entity-framework-migrations

Here is some working EF6 migration code:

```
Database.SetInitializer<CmContext>(null);
var settings = new MigrationsConfiguration();
var migrator = new DbMigrator(settings);
migrator.Update();
```

What is the equivalent using EF Core?

Answer (score 20):

In beta 7 and on, use:

```
using Microsoft.Data.Entity;

...

context.Database.Migrate();
```

Comment: This seems to be changed in beta7? looking for some info about how to migrate beta6 to beta7, ApplyMigrations isn't there anymore, ContextType attribute seems to have gone.. or my project just have gone haywire.. again. ;)

Comment: Start over - much have changed!

Comment: where do you put this code?  Seems initializers and the like have changed so much I don't know where this would go.

Comment: In your application startup code, only to be run once

Comment: `Migrate` is an extension, so you have to `using Microsoft.Data.Entity;`.

Comment: @ErikEJ, where would be a good place to call it at your ASP.NET Core app entry point that DI is ready?

Comment: @shimmy https://blog.rsuter.com/automatically-migrate-your-entity-framework-core-managed-database-on-asp-net-core-application-start/

Comment: @ErikEJ, the kind of answer I was after. Thank you!

Answer (score 16):

For Entity Framework Core 1.0.0, ensure you have the `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Relational` NuGet package. Then import this namespace:

```
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
```

Finally, get hold of a `DbContext` and run:

```
context.Database.Migrate();
```

Comment: Will `context.Database.Migrate()` creates a tables or else will create only Database?

Comment: Migration creates all schema elements, including tables.

Comment: For me its creating only Database, there is no tables in the Database. I have this line of code in `startup.cs` and I am running `Add-Migration` command

Answer (score 3):

According to the Microsoft documentation, for more advanced scenarios than simply applying the migrations which are already present in your project file structure, you can use the EF Core `IMigrator` service. You can easily access the internal implementation by utilizing the following access code:

```
var migrator = myDbContext.GetInfrastructure().GetService<IMigrator>();
```