# EntityFramework 7 - CodeFirst - SQLite - Manage DB using ApplyMigrations at runtime

Tags: sqlite, entity-framework-core

I am well on my way to utilizing EF7 CodeFirst with SQLite...but really want to employ DB Migrations at runtime. This is a desktop application (Click-once deployment) meant to sync with a main database when connection is available, and provide offline data when no connection is present.

I have pulled down the nuget pre-release versions and all is working, except I cannot find any documentation of how to apply the migrations at runtime. I can successfully Add-Migrations and manually Apply-Migrations...but need a way to programatically Apply-Migrations at runtime.

I've also browsed the EF7 open-source project, but could not get anywhere there.

Versions I'm using: Latest Pre-release as of 9/15/2015
    EntityFramework.Sqlite v7.0.0-beta7
    EntityFramework.Relational v7.0.0-beta7
    EntityFramework.Commands v7.0.0-beta7
    ...et al...you get the picture.

I am asking for help to apply runtime migrations...or what is the documented/recommended path for programatically maintaining a local/embedded db using EF7 CodeFirst SQLite?

**UPDATE:**
I went back to EF6 with SQLite but then found out that there is not SQLMigrationGenerator for SQLite.

**EDIT:**
I believe ApplyMigrations() method referenced in one of the notes has been deprecated. Searching the repository, there is no reference to "ApplyMigrations".

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to apply migrations from code (EF7)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31710038/how-to-apply-migrations-from-code-ef7)

Comment: SQLite is very limited when it comes to schema changes, but you can try the DevArt provider for EF6

Comment: Appreciate the info. I found that thread, but I'm afraid that they may have removed the runtime Apply-Migrations capability. Digging around in the GitHub repository, I found a reference to try Update-Database. Searching for this yielded some possibilities. I will investigate and report back.

Comment: I can do what I need to do with SQLite at the level of migration management...so far. This has to be a target deployment for Entity Framework as many Windows 10 IoT devices, and desktop apps, are going to want an effective ORM like EF.

Comment: `ApplyMigrations` was renamed to `Migrate`.

Answer (score 1):

Today you can invoke the extension method `Migrate` on the `DatabaseFacade`.

This method is only available when the `using Microsoft.Data.Entity` statement is present. It comes from the `RelationalDatabaseFacadeExtensions` class that is part of the `EntityFramework.Relational` package.

Still have to find out how to migrate up and down from the API.

Comment: I'm also waiting for the ability to diff between applied migrations and ones that the current codebase needs. Without it, `EnsureDeleted()` can really only be used by catching known exceptions or during testing/early dev to mimic the old delete and recreate every time initializer.